# When does the "Other Calendar" from Google Calendar get updated?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have added a calendar to my google calendar by using option **"Add by URL"**.

This URL is from web application, so when I make some changes to the Schedule date of the task in web application it should also get reflected in google calendar that I have added.

When I add the calendar for first time all the schedule dates are shown in calendar but when some rescheduling is done those changes are not reflected.

So I would like to know the frequency at which google updates the "Other Calendar". Is is after every **24** hours?

**Notes** : ICalendar format is used for adding events.

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is not yet supported as of now.

This question was also asked in this [calendar forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/VNHydDCukDU;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/category$3Acalendar-setup-and-privacy%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) where the suggested workaround was:

> just add another calendar by url, but this time change URL a little
>   bit so that Google thinks that this is a new, different calendar:
>
> http://server.com/my/calendar/feed.php
>   http://server.com/my/calendar/feed.php?version=2
>
> Your server will just ignore this extra parameter.

Comment: I tried this technique it works but then every time a new calendar gets added, and I don't want such thing. I want the same calendar to get updated.